# fwrite() blocks call and doesn`t write to file

Tags: c, linux, tcp, fwrite

I have a TCP Concurent server and I have a problem with my client side.I am trying to send a file from server to client but the client won't save to file and I'm guessing `fwrite()` call is to blame.

Server Code :

```
 while (1)
{
    /* pregatirea structurii client */
  len = sizeof (from);
  bzero (&from, sizeof (from));

  /* a venit un client, acceptam conexiunea */
  client = accept (sd, (struct sockaddr *) &from, &len);

  /* eroare la acceptarea conexiunii de la un client */
  if (client < 0)
    {
      perror ("[server] Eroare la accept().\n");
      continue;
    }

      if (nr>30) 
    {
      char maxMsg[100]="Numarul maxim de participanti a fost atins.\n";
      write(client,maxMsg,50);
          close(client);
      nr--;
}
  else  
    {
      printf("[server] S-a conectat clientul cu descriptorul %d, de la adresa %s.\n",client, conv_addr (from));
      nr++;
    }
  fflush (stdout);

pid=fork();
if(pid<0)
  {
    printf ("[server] Eroare la fork().\n");
  }
if(pid==0)
  {
    /* copil/client  */
        if (welcome(client))
      {
        sendTest(client);
    printf ("[server] S-a deconectat clientul cu descriptorul %d.\n",client);
            fflush (stdout);
    close (client);     /* inchidem conexiunea cu clientul */
        nr--;
    close(sd);
    exit(0);
      }
  }

}               /* while */
}               /* main */
int welcome(int client)
{
 char buffer[100];      /* mesajul */
 int bytes;         /* numarul de octeti cititi/scrisi */
char name[100];     //mesajul primit de la client 
char msgrasp[100]=" ";        //mesaj de raspuns pentru client

bytes = read (client, name, sizeof (buffer));
if (bytes < 0)
{
  perror ("Eroare la read() de la client.\n");
  return 0;
}
printf ("[server] Numele participantului este %s\n", name);

/*pregatim mesajul de raspuns */
bzero(msgrasp,100);
strcat(msgrasp,"Hello ");
int ln = strlen(name) - 1;
if (name[ln] == '\n') 
name[ln] = '\0';
strcat(msgrasp,name);
strcat(msgrasp,". Please wait for your test.\n");

printf("[server]Trimitem mesajul inapoi...%s\n",msgrasp);

if (bytes && write (client, msgrasp, bytes) < 0)
{
  perror ("[server] Eroare la write() catre client.\n");
  return 0;
}

return bytes;
}


int sendTest(int client)
{
FILE *fd;
int rand;
char filename[100];
char buffer[256];
int nread;

/* pregatim fisierul/testul pentru trimitere  */
bzero(filename,100);
rand = randInt();
sprintf(filename,"%d",rand);
strcat(filename,".c");

fd = fopen(filename, "r");
 if (fd == NULL)
   {
     perror("[server] Eroare la open().\n");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

/* trimitem numele fisierului */ 
write(client,filename,sizeof(filename));
printf("name=%s\n",filename);

/* Sending file data */
nread=fread(buffer,1,256,fd);
if(nread>0)
 {
  printf("[server] Sending file.\n");
  write(client,buffer,nread);
}

if (nread < 256)
{
  if (feof(fd))
    printf("End of file\n");
  if (ferror(fd))
    printf("Error reading\n");
}

fclose(fd);

return 0;
}
```

Client Code:

```
if (connect (sd, (struct sockaddr *) &server,sizeof (struct sockaddr)) == -1)
 {
  perror ("[client]Eroare la connect().\n");
  return errno;
 }

 /* citirea mesajului */
 bzero (name, 100);
 printf ("[client]Introduceti un nume: ");
 fflush (stdout);
 read (0, name, 100);

 /* trimiterea mesajului la server */
 if (write (sd, name, 100) <= 0)
 {
  perror ("[client]Eroare la write() spre server.\n");
  return errno;
 }

 /* citirea raspunsului dat de server 
 (apel blocant pina cind serverul raspunde) */
 if (read (sd, name, 100) < 0)
 {
  perror ("[client]Eroare la read() de la server.\n");
  return errno;
 }
 /* afisam mesajul primit */
 printf ("[client]Mesajul primit este: %s\n", name);
 fflush(stdout);

 /* primim numele fisierului  */
 read(sd,filename,sizeof(filename));
 fflush(stdout);

 char filename2[50]="test2.c";
 received_file = fopen(filename2, "w+");
 if (received_file == NULL)
 {
  printf("Eroare la fopen().\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 bzero(recvBuff,256);
 while((bytesReceived = read(sd, recvBuff, 256)) > 0)
 {
    printf("Bytes received %d\n",bytesReceived);
    //fwrite(recvBuff, 8,bytesReceived,received_file);
    fwrite("asdf",4,1,received_file);
    printf("writing");
 }
 printf("wrote");
 fclose(received_file);
 printf("closed");

if(bytesReceived < 0)
{
    printf("Eroare la read.\n");
}


/* inchidem conexiunea, am terminat */
close (sd);
```

The file server sends:

```
 /*
 Welcome. Here you will resolve your problem. Please use <insert comand here> 
 to send back the file when you are done.

 Your task is to do <insert problem description here>.
 Time allocated: 20 minutes;

 May the force be with you.

 */
```

Also the `recvBuff` has all the text sent by the server.
Thank you in advance for helping me.

**EDIT:**
Here is a image of the output. The client stuck after the `printf("Bytes received %d\n",bytesReceived);` which is before fwrite call.
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foABt.png)

Comment: when i said i blame the fwrite i meant i`ve done something wrong and now is not working :)

Comment: "not working" is obviously not a useful problem description. Describe exactly what the behaviour of your program is (e.g. the actual output) and how you concluded that `fwrite` is the problem. Providing *specific* information will help others to help you.

Comment: What purpose does `fflush(stdout)` serve? I want to hear this from you so that I know you understand your code.

Comment: the purpose of `fflush(stdout)` is to be sure that the output is saved on disk

Comment: Please try to isolate the fault: a link to a wall of error messges in Romanian isn't going to help solve the problem.

Comment: Your conclusion is probably wrong. `printf("writing");` add a `\n` at the end of that `printf` string. Because `printf` is line buffered. So it probably did execute but just didn't flush to `stdout`. It's more likely blocked on the next `read`. Or even better, use a debugger to verify exactly where the code is blocked.

Comment: @kaylum you are right. writing apeared after adding `\n`. i alos did that to next one(`printf("wrote\n");`) but this one didn't get outputed so now i think it might be the `while` is wrong. also i don`t know how to use a debugger on linux. is quite new to me.

Comment: Don't guess. Debug. You aren't writing `msggrasp` correctly, as the value of `bytes` at that point has nothing to do with its length. Writing to a local disk doesn't block. The purpose of `fflush()` is to flush the specified `FILE*` regardless of what it is being written to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close the `client` descriptor in the code of the server: you forked and close in the child, but not in the parent, so the connection remains open and the client waits blocked in its `read` for data that will never come.
That should correct it (your code is too badly written to see if something else is also wrong):

```
if(pid==0)
  {
    /* copil/client  */
    if (welcome(client))
      {
        sendTest(client);
        printf ("[server] S-a deconectat clientul cu descriptorul %d.\n",client);
            fflush (stdout);
        close (client);     /* inchidem conexiunea cu clientul */
        nr--;
        close(sd);
        exit(0);
      }
  } else // close the descriptor as parent is not in charge of managing the connection anymore
  {
    close(client);
  }
```

Comment: thank you that fixed the problem. and sorry for my code.

Comment: mark this as the correct answer then, thanks